# black & white colormap (with dashes, dots etc)

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I am using matplotlib to create 2d line-plots. For the purposes of publication, I would like to have those plots in black and white (**not** grayscale), and I am struggling to find a non-intrusive solution for that.

Gnuplot automatically alters dashing patterns for different lines, is something similar possible with matplotlib?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Below I provide functions to convert a colored line to a black line with unique style. My quick test showed that after 7 lines, the colors repeated. If this is not the case (and I made a mistake), then a minor adjustment is needed for the "constant" `COLORMAP` in the provided routine.

Here's the routine and example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def setAxLinesBW(ax):
    """
    Take each Line2D in the axes, ax, and convert the line style to be 
    suitable for black and white viewing.
    """
    MARKERSIZE = 3

    COLORMAP = {
        'b': {'marker': None, 'dash': (None,None)},
        'g': {'marker': None, 'dash': [5,5]},
        'r': {'marker': None, 'dash': [5,3,1,3]},
        'c': {'marker': None, 'dash': [1,3]},
        'm': {'marker': None, 'dash': [5,2,5,2,5,10]},
        'y': {'marker': None, 'dash': [5,3,1,2,1,10]},
        'k': {'marker': 'o', 'dash': (None,None)} #[1,2,1,10]}
        }


    lines_to_adjust = ax.get_lines()
    try:
        lines_to_adjust += ax.get_legend().get_lines()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    for line in lines_to_adjust:
        origColor = line.get_color()
        line.set_color('black')
        line.set_dashes(COLORMAP[origColor]['dash'])
        line.set_marker(COLORMAP[origColor]['marker'])
        line.set_markersize(MARKERSIZE)

def setFigLinesBW(fig):
    """
    Take each axes in the figure, and for each line in the axes, make the
    line viewable in black and white.
    """
    for ax in fig.get_axes():
        setAxLinesBW(ax)

xval = np.arange(100)*.01

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)

ax.plot(xval,np.cos(2*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(3*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(4*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(5*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(6*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(7*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(8*np.pi*xval))

ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(2*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(3*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(4*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(5*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(6*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(7*np.pi*xval))
ax.plot(xval,np.cos(8*np.pi*xval))

fig.savefig("colorDemo.png")
setFigLinesBW(fig)
fig.savefig("bwDemo.png")
```

This provides the following two plots:
First in color:
[image]
Then in black and white:
[image]

You can adjust how each color is converted to a style. If you just want to only play with the dash style (-. vs. -- vs. whatever pattern you want), set the `COLORMAP` corresponding 'marker' value to `None` and adjusted the 'dash' pattern, or vice versa.

For example, the last color in the dictionary is 'k' (for black); originally I had only a dashed pattern `[1,2,1,10]`, corresponding to one pixel shown, two not, one shown, 10 not, which is a dot-dot-space pattern. Then I commented that out, setting the dash to (None,None), a very formal way of saying solid line, and added the marker 'o', for circle.

I also set a 'constant' MARKERSIZE, which will set the size of each marker, because I found the default size to be a little large.

This obviously does not handle the case when your lines already have a dash or marker patter, but you can use these routines as a starting point to build a more sophisticated converter. For example if you original plot had a red solid line and a red dotted line, they both would turn into black dash-dot lines with these routines. Something to keep in mind when you use them.

Comment: ``for line in ax.get_lines() + ax.get_legend().get_lines():``

Change the loop to the above line to also change the legend.

Comment: `ax.get_legend()` returns `None` in matplotlib 1.3.1 when there is no legend, which makes the example above fail for me.  It is great after a quick fix, however, so thanks!

Comment: Great answer, @Yann! I just ran into this issue in revising a paper for publication and it's nice to have a ready answer to adapt to my situation.

Comment: @Yann: Thank you very much for the great answer! But could you perhaps include something like:    ``try:
        lines_to_cycle = ax.get_lines() + ax.get_legend().get_lines()
    except AttributeError:
        lines_to_cycle = ax.get_lines()
    for line in lines_to_cycle:``
For the reasons mentioned by Abraham D Flaxman.

Comment: Hi, how can I plot a marker with while colour filled in and the border in black?

Answer (score 15):

#### TL;DR

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
monochrome = (cycler('color', ['k']) * cycler('marker', ['', '.']) *
              cycler('linestyle', ['-', '--', ':', '=.']))
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=monochrome)
...
```

### Extended answer

Newer `matplotlib` releases introduced a new `rcParams`, namely `axes.prop_cycle`

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
Out[2]: cycler('color', ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k'])
```

For the precanned styles, available by `plt.style.use(...)` or `with plt.style.context(...):`, the `prop_cycle` is equivalent to the traditional *and deprecated* `axes.color_cycle`

```
In [3]: plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']
/.../__init__.py:892: UserWarning: axes.color_cycle is deprecated and replaced with axes.prop_cycle; please use the latter.
  warnings.warn(self.msg_depr % (key, alt_key))
Out[3]: ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']
```

but the `cycler` object has many more possibilities, in particular a complex `cycler` can be composed from simpler ones, referring to different properties, using `+` and `*`, meaning respectively zipping and Cartesian product.

Here we import the `cycler` helper function, we define 3 simple `cycler` that refer to different properties and finally compose them using the Cartesian product

```
In [4]: from cycler import cycler
In [5]: color_c = cycler('color', ['k'])
In [6]: style_c = cycler('linestyle', ['-', '--', ':', '-.'])
In [7]: markr_c = cycler('marker', ['', '.', 'o'])
In [8]: c_cms = color_c * markr_c * style_c
In [9]: c_csm = color_c * style_c * markr_c
```

Here we have two different(?) complex `cycler` and yes, they are different because this operation is non-commutative, have a look

```
In [10]: for d in c_csm: print('\t'.join(d[k] for k in d))
-               k
-       .       k
-       o       k
--              k
--      .       k
--      o       k
:               k
:       .       k
:       o       k
-.              k
-.      .       k
-.      o       k

In [11]: for d in c_cms: print('\t'.join(d[k] for k in d))
-               k
--              k
:               k
-.              k
-       .       k
--      .       k
:       .       k
-.      .       k
-       o       k
--      o       k
:       o       k
-.      o       k
```

The elemental cycle that changes faster is the last in the product, etc., this is important if we want a certain order in the styling of lines.

How to use the composition of `cycler`s?  By the means of `plt.rc`, or an equivalent way to modify the `rcParams` of `matplotlib`.  E.g.,

```
In [12]: %matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg
In [13]: import numpy as np
In [14]: x = np.linspace(0, 8, 101)
In [15]: y = np.cos(np.arange(7)+x[:,None])
In [16]: plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=c_cms)
In [17]: plt.plot(x, y);
In [18]: plt.grid();
```

[image]

Of course this is just an example, and the OP can mix and match different properties to achieve the most pleasing visual output.

PS I forgot to mention that this approach automatically takes care of line samples in the legend box,
[image]

Comment: This is so clean.

Answer (score 3):

I heavily did use Yann's code, but today I read an answer from [Can i cycle through line styles in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799156/can-i-cycle-through-line-styles-in-matplotlib) So now I will make my BW plots in this way:

```
import pylab as plt
from itertools import cycle
lines = ["k-","k--","k-.","k:"]
linecycler = cycle(lines)
plt.figure()
for i in range(4):
    x = range(i,i+10)
    plt.plot(range(10),x,next(linecycler))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Things like `plot(x,y,'k-.')` will produce the black (`'k'`) dot-dashed (`'-.'`) line. Is that not what you a looking for?

Comment: Nit really, I would have to set it for every plot and dataset by hand.