# Matplotlib: how to set dashes in a dictionary?

Tags: matplotlib

Can anybody tell me how to use a custom dash sequence in a dictionary. I cannot get that running and the only  thing I cannot work with (not a programmer) is the documentation =-(

```
def lineCycler(): #must be invoked for every plot again to get the same results in every plot
    #hasy="#7b9aae"
    _styles = [{'color':'#b21a6a', 'ls':'-'},
               {'color':'#65a4cb', 'ls':'[5,2,10,5]'},# this shoul be some custom dash sequnece
               {'color':'#22b27c', 'ls':'-.'},
               {'color':'k', 'ls':'--'}
            ]

    _linecycler=cycle(_styles)
    return _linecycler
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dashes` keyword for that (and you need a list, instead of a string):

```py
def lineCycler(): 
    _styles = [{'color':'#b21a6a', 'ls':'-'},
               {'color':'#65a4cb', 'dashes':[5,2,10,5]},
               {'color':'#22b27c', 'ls':'-.'},
               {'color':'k', 'ls':'--'}
            ]

    _linecycler=cycle(_styles)
    return _linecycler
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested a (felt like) million setups but this is missed.