# TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    """x, random=random.random -> shuffle list x in place; return None.

    Optional arg random is a 0-argument function returning a random
    float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, the standard random.random.
    """

    randbelow = self._randbelow
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = randbelow(i+1) if random is None else int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

When I run the `shuffle` function it raises the following error, why is that?

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: seems to be an python3 error

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Clearly you're passing in `d.keys()` to your `shuffle` function.  Probably this was written with python2.x (when `d.keys()` returned a list).  With python3.x, `d.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object which behaves a lot more like a `set` than a `list`.  As such, it can't be indexed.

The solution is to pass `list(d.keys())` (or simply `list(d)`) to `shuffle`.

Comment: . . . Or just `list(d)` which will give you a list of keys on both python2.x and python3.x without making any copies :-)

Comment: This is a strange breaking change design decision for python3.

Comment: You might think so, but I definitely think that it was the correct decision.  The `dict_keys` object behaves a lot more like just the keys half of a dict.  Specifically, they support O(1) membership testing (and other set-like methods that can be implemented efficiently on top of that fact).  These things aren't possible with a list and if you want a list of the dict's keys, you've always been able to simply do `list(your_dictionary)` to get it.

Comment: this is helpful for me to see that python3 requires us to wrap the dictionary with list.

Comment: what does shuffle mean?

Comment: @Crt -- `shuffle` is the name of the function in the original poster's code (the function that is throwing the error).  Looking at the code, I think that it was copy/pasted from `random.shuffle`'s implementation in the standard library :-)

Comment: Is there a good reason for this design decision ? It appears to be an unnecessary type that adds no additional value - just makes things harder than they need to be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @firdaus -- Are you asking about the design decision for `d.keys()` to return something other than a `list`?  I think that this was a great decision.  The `list` previously returned had order (because it is a list), but the order had no semantic value (because dict were unordered).  It also made a copy of the collection rather than returning something that is a lightweight view over the container (so the python3.x version is more efficient).  If you need a list, it's trivial to construct one and pay that performance hit, but otherwise you shouldn't have to.

Comment: @mgilson If ordering is the only concern  - the designers should have returned the keys and values as a `set` type rather than introducing a new, overly specific and rather verbose type which achieves exactly the same thing (except more painfully). This new type looks like compiler / language engineers getting a bit carried away rather than constraining their imagination.

Comment: `set` aren't ordered or indexible so that wouldn't solve the `shuffle` problem here and it would involve a performance hit because it would need to copy the data.  The benefits of a new type is that it can be a lot more efficient for common use-cases and still preserve the set interface for use in a lot of use-cases.  In any case, I'm not a python core developer, so these aren't _my_ decisions.  I think their design decisions in this regard make a lot of sense, but you're certainly welcome to disagree.

Answer (score 13):

You're passing the result of `somedict.keys()` to the function. In Python 3, `dict.keys` doesn't return a list, but a set-like object that represents a view of the dictionary's keys and (being set-like) doesn't support indexing.

To fix the problem, use `list(somedict.keys())` to collect the keys, and work with that.

Answer (score 13):

Convert an iterable to a list may have a cost. Instead, to get the the first item, you can use:

```
next(iter(keys))
```

Or, if you want to iterate over all items, you can use:

```
items = iter(keys)
while True:
    try:
        item = next(items)
    except StopIteration as e:
        pass # finish
```

Comment: The OP _doesn't_ want to just access the first item or iterate over the items in one go, they need random access over items in order to shuffle them. With those requirements, converting the iterable to a list is exactly the right approach. Also, your second snippet can be replaced with the clearer and more efficient `for item in keys: pass`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2 dict.keys() return a list, whereas in Python 3 it returns a generator.

You could only iterate over it's values else you may have to explicitly convert it to a list i.e. pass it to a list function.

Comment: I don't think it's a generator, or else you'd be able to use next(dict.keys()), no?

Comment: In order to do that simply  ```iter(dict.keys())``` or ```iter(dict.values())```. The output of dict.keys() is basically a view object. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to implement shuffle when it already exists? Stay on the shoulders of giants.

```
import random

d1 = {0:'zero', 1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three', 4:'four',
     5:'five', 6:'six', 7:'seven', 8:'eight', 9:'nine'}

keys = list(d1)
random.shuffle(keys)

d2 = {}
for key in keys: d2[key] = d1[key]

print(d1)
print(d2)
```

Comment: The answer is general-knowledge relevant, but it doesn't address to what the OP was asking.

Comment: You're right. It seems he want to implement his own randomizer.

Comment: psah, maybe he didn't actually know that he could use the built-in, but the question actually seems to be about a type-error. Still, I hope he switched and used your option (unless it is something very specific) to follow the basic DRY and code-economy principles.