# Plot a histogram from a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, histogram

I created a `dictionary` that counts the occurrences in a `list` of every key and I would now like to plot the histogram of its content.

This is the content of the dictionary I want to plot:

```
{1: 27, 34: 1, 3: 72, 4: 62, 5: 33, 6: 36, 7: 20, 8: 12, 9: 9, 10: 6, 11: 5, 12: 8, 2: 74, 14: 4, 15: 3, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1, 19: 1, 21: 1, 27: 2}
```

So far I wrote this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pos = np.arange(len(myDictionary.keys()))
width = 1.0     # gives histogram aspect to the bar diagram

ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xticks(pos + (width / 2))
ax.set_xticklabels(myDictionary.keys())

plt.bar(myDictionary.keys(), ******, width, color='g')
#                            ^^^^^^ what should I put here?
plt.show()
```

I tried by simply doing

```
plt.bar(myDictionary.keys(), myDictionary, width, color='g')
```

but this is the result:

[image]

and I don't know why the 3 bars are shifted and also I'd like the histogram to be displayed in a ordered fashion.

Can somebody tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use the function for plotting histograms like this:

```
a = np.random.random_integers(0,10,20) #example list of values
plt.hist(a)
plt.show()
```

Or you can use `myDictionary` just like this:

```
plt.bar(myDictionary.keys(), myDictionary.values(), width, color='g')
```

Comment: Use plt.bar when your keys are strings !

Comment: is it possible to display the resulting bins ordered ?

Answer (score 41):

With Python 3 you need to use `list(your_dict.keys())` instead of `your_dict.keys()` (otherwise you get [TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17322668/395857)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dictionary = {1: 27, 34: 1, 3: 72, 4: 62, 5: 33, 6: 36, 7: 20, 8: 12, 9: 9, 10: 6, 11: 5, 
              12: 8, 2: 74, 14: 4, 15: 3, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1, 19: 1, 21: 1, 27: 2}
plt.bar(list(dictionary.keys()), dictionary.values(), color='g')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Tested with Matplotlib 2.0.0 and python 3.5.

FYI: [Plotting a python dict in order of key values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37266341/395857)

Answer (score 5):

If you **really** want to use the [`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) function (for example to use the bins keyword), you can always convert your Counter to a list

With your code :

```
mydict = {1: 27, 34: 1, 3: 72, 4: 62, 5: 33, 6: 36, 7: 20, 8: 12, 9: 9, 10: 6, 11: 5, 12: 8, 2: 74, 14: 4, 15: 3, 16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1, 19: 1, 21: 1, 27: 2}

mylist = [key for key, val in mydict.items() for _ in range(val)]
plt.hist(mylist, bins=20)
```

will output
[image]

```
plt.hist(mylist, bins=5)
```

will output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
values = [] #in same order as traversing keys
keys = [] #also needed to preserve order
for key in myDictionary.keys():
  keys.append(key)
  values.append(myDictionary[key])
```

Use 'keys' and 'values'. This ensures that the order is preserved.

Comment: In a standard Python implementation you don't need to do that, as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.items)

Comment: I think he means use `x,y = zip(myDictionary.items())`

Answer (score 0):

In case the keys of the `myDictionary` are not uniformed distributed, its helpful to use the keys as `str`:

```
plt.bar([ str(i) for i in myDictionary.keys()], myDictionary.values(), color='g')
```