# Plotting an histogram from a dictionary values in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, plot

I am trying to plot an histogram. The data for this histogram come from a dictionary that contains a frequency list, and all I need is to plot either:

- A histogram or,
- A barplot of the values of each element (the histogram can be derived from here : ) )

Here's an example of what the dictionary looks like:

```
{0: 282, 1: 152, 2: 131, 3: 122, 4: 108, 5: 101, 6: 106, 7: 91, 8: 96, 9: 92,
...
1147: 1, 1157: 1, 1186: 1, 1217: 1, 1236: 1, 1251: 1, 1255: 1, 1291: 1, 1372: 1, 1402: 1}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use the python library mathplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/) or write everything to a file and use gnuplot or R to plot that.

Comment: Bar chart demo - http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot a histogram from a Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195179/plot-a-histogram-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this quickly using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([your_dict])
df = df.T
df.hist()
```

Note, `your_dict` should be inside a list.

Answer (score 0):

Another way without using `pandas` :

```
h = [v for v in your_dict.values()]
plt.hist(h)
```

This allows easy filtering and modifying, e.g.

```
h = [np.log(v) for v in your_dict.values() if v>0]
plt.hist(v)
```