# ipython pylab: print histogram from dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, ipython

I have a dictionary `d`:

```
d = {'apples': 5, 'oranges': 2, 'bananas': 2, 'lemons': 1, 'coconuts': 1}
```

how can I display it graphically, as a histogram using (`pylab/matplotlib/
pandas/what-ever-is-best-suitable-for-simple-histograms`)

What I am looking for is a graphical analogy to the following:

```
X
X
X
X  X  X
X  X  X  X  X
-------------
A  O  B  L  C
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot a histogram from a Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195179/plot-a-histogram-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d = {'apples': 5, 'oranges': 2, 'bananas': 2, 'lemons': 1, 'coconuts': 1}

plt.bar(range(len(d)), d.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(d)), d.keys(), rotation=25)
```

[image]

Or, to make it colorful:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d = {'apples': 5, 'oranges': 2, 'bananas': 2, 'lemons': 1, 'coconuts': 1}

jet = plt.get_cmap('jet')
N = len(d)
plt.bar(range(N), d.values(), align='center', color=jet(np.linspace(0, 1.0, N)))
plt.xticks(range(N), d.keys(), rotation=25)
```

[image]

Comment: actually, your example does not work when I draw plot inline  `ipython qtconsole --pylab=inline`. It only works when the plots are displayed in an external window.

Comment: I've modified the code so that the plot will be displayed inline with the ipython qtconsole.

Comment: thanks, but it still does not work properly: `plt.bar` draws the histogram (the bars) but with numbers instead of labels. The second command `plt.xticks` draws a second empty graph with labels (without bars)

Comment: You have to paste all the commands into one cell before evaluating.

Comment: what do you mean "paste into one cell". What is a cell?

Comment: By "cell" I mean one input line -- the thing that begins with `In [...]:`. The term may be is a hangover from Mathematica. They look more like cells when you run `ipython notebook`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `plot` and set `kind='bar':

```
In [252]:

d = {'apples': [5], 'oranges':[2], 'bananas': [2], 'lemons': [1], 'coconuts': [1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.plot(kind='bar')
Out[252]:
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0xb54b0f0>
```

[image]