# Plotting a python dict in order of key values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python dictionary that looks like this:

```
In[1]: dict_concentration
Out[2] : {0: 0.19849878712984576,
5000: 0.093917341754771386,
10000: 0.075060643507712022,
20000: 0.06673074282575861,
30000: 0.057119318961966224,
50000: 0.046134834546203485,
100000: 0.032495766396631424,
200000: 0.018536317451599615,
500000: 0.0059499290585381479}
```

They keys are type int, the values are type float64. 
Unfortunately, when I try to plot this with lines, matplotlib connects the wrong points (plot attached). How can I make it connect lines in order of the key values? [image]

Answer (score 131):

Python dictionaries are unordered. If you want an ordered dictionary, use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

In your case, sort the dict by key before plotting,

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

lists = sorted(d.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples

x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

---

Here is the result.
[image]

Comment: Very useful to know that the * unpacks the tuple.

Comment: If you wanted to sort by values, use ```lists = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)```

Answer (score 18):

Simply pass the sorted items from the dictionary to the `plot()` function. `concentration.items()` returns a list of tuples where each tuple contains a key from the dictionary and its corresponding value.

You can take advantage of list unpacking (with `*`) to pass the sorted data directly to zip, and then again to pass it into `plot()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

concentration = {
    0: 0.19849878712984576,
    5000: 0.093917341754771386,
    10000: 0.075060643507712022,
    20000: 0.06673074282575861,
    30000: 0.057119318961966224,
    50000: 0.046134834546203485,
    100000: 0.032495766396631424,
    200000: 0.018536317451599615,
    500000: 0.0059499290585381479}

plt.plot(*zip(*sorted(concentration.items())))
plt.show()
```

`sorted()` sorts tuples in the order of the tuple's items so you don't need to specify a `key` function because the tuples returned by `dict.item()` already begin with the key value.

Answer (score -1):

Easier way:

```py
plt.plot(list(dict.keys()), list(dict.values()))
```

Comment: That’s insertion order (nowadays) and not key order.