# How to update the value of a key in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which represents a book shop. The keys represent the book title and values represent the number of copies of the book present. When books are sold from the shop, the number of copies of the book must decrease.

I have written a code for decreasing the number of copies of the sold book, but on printing the dictionary after the update, I get the initial dictionary and not the updated one.

```
 n = input("Enter number of books in shop: ")

 book_shop = {} # Creating a dictionary book_shop

 # Entering elements into the dictionary
 for i in range(n):
     book_title = raw_input("Enter book title: ")
     book_no = input("Enter no of copies: ")
     book_shop[book_title] = book_no

 choice = raw_input("Do you want to sell?")
 if (choice in 'yesYES'):
        for i in range(n):
             print("Which book do you want to sell: ", book_shop)
             ch1 = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")
             if(book_shop.keys()[i] == ch1):
                    book_shop.keys()[i] = (book_shop.values()[i]-1)
                    break
        
 print(book_shop)
```

I would like to solve the problem in the simplest way possible. Have I missed any logic or any line in the code?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Well you could directly substract from the value by just referencing the key. Which in my opinion is simpler.

```
>>> books = {}
>>> books['book'] = 3       
>>> books['book'] -= 1   
>>> books   
{'book': 2}
```

In your case:

```
book_shop[ch1] -= 1
```

Comment: I modified the line: book_shop.keys()[i]=(book_shop.values()[i]-1) to
book_shop.keys()[i]-=1, but still it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Modify it to `book_shop[ch1] -= 1`

Comment: Thank you,it worked. Could you tell me what was the mistake in my code??

Comment: Referencing your dicts via `dict_keys()[index]` is a bit wonky, probably something to do with that. By the way, in python3 that type of accessing is no longer possible, so it's probably a good idea to just index direcly via keys and directly modify the values as shown in my answer.

Comment: I am using python 2.7, and the referencing dictionary using dict.keys()[index] didn't work in that also. So, this line: book_shop.keys()[i]=(book_shop.values()[i]-1) is invalid?

Comment: Well then, there's your problem. [At some point in the dark history keys() used to return a list that you could access by indexing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322668/typeerror-dict-keys-object-does-not-support-indexing). I don't have python 2.7 even installed, but at least in python 3 that line does fail, yes. Even if it's not invalid, it's not really neat looking, is it?

Answer (score 12):

```
d = {'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 2}
d.update({'A': 2})
```

print(d)

```
{'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 2}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply specify another value to the existed key:

```
t = {}
t['A'] = 1
t['B'] = 5
t['C'] = 2

print(t)

{'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 2}
```

Now let's update one of the keys:

```
t['B'] = 3

print(t)

{'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the list `book_shop.values()[i]`, which is not getting updated in the dictionary. Whenever you call the `values()` method, it will give you the values available in dictionary, and here you are not modifying the data of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = eval(input('Num books: '))
books = {}
for i in range(n):
    titlez = input("Enter Title: ")
    copy = eval(input("Num of copies: "))
    books[titlez] = copy

prob = input('Sell a book; enter YES or NO: ')
if prob == 'YES' or 'yes':
    choice = input('Enter book title: ')
    if choice in books:
        init_num = books[choice]
        init_num -= 1
        books[choice] = init_num
        print(books)
```

Comment: Could you please add a few words to help explain your answer?