# How to update certain dictionary key value in python

Tags: python

I have a below dictionary and want to update certain value of that dictionary

**for example :**

```
my_dict = {'name':'Raju','surname':'XYZ','age':13,'dateofjoin':'12-Jul-2017'}
```

The value for `dateofjoin : 12-Jul-2017`  need to update to `15-Aug-2017` and `age : 13` to `18`

**So my expected output is :**

```
my_dict = {'name':'Raju','surname':'XYZ','age':18,'dateofjoin':'15-Aug-2017'}
```

Comment: `my_dict['dateofjoin'] = '15-Aug-2017'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063744/how-to-update-the-value-of-a-key-in-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_dict['dateofjoin'] = '15-Aug-2017'
my_dict['age']=18
```

This will directly update your existing dictionary. Once you run this, your output for my_dict will be

```
{'name': 'Raju', 'surname': 'XYZ', 'age': 18, 'dateofjoin': '15-Aug-2017'}
```

Answer (score 1):

To update a specific key value pair of a dictionary in python you can just use

```
dict[key] = value
```

for your code it means

```
my_dict['dateofjoin'] = '15-Aug-2017'
my_dict['age']=18
```