# 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm using Learn Python the Hard Way for studying Python, and I'm running into the `'dict_keys' object does not support indexing error` when I run the following code that is provided as an example:

```
import random
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
    "class %%%(%%%):":
      "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
      "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
      "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
    "*** = %%%()":
      "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
    "***.***(@@@)":
      "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@.",
    "***.*** = '***'":
      "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

# do they want to drill phrases first
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True
else:
    PHRASE_FIRST = False

# load up the words from the website
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())


def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
                   random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

    for sentence in snippet, phrase:
        result = sentence[:]

        # fake class names
        for word in class_names:
            result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

        # fake other names
        for word in other_names:
            result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

        # fake parameter lists
        for word in param_names:
            result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

        results.append(result)

    return results


# keep going until they hit CTRL-D
try:
    while True:
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        for snippet in snippets:
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question = list(answer)
                answer = list(question)

            print(question)

            input("> ")
            print("ANSWER:  %s\n\n" % answer)
except EOFError:
    print("\nBye")
```

This code is meant for Python 2.x, and I'm using Python 3.5. I saw the following post, but couldn't translate the solution to the one above: [TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322668/typeerror-dict-keys-object-does-not-support-indexing). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you be so kind to accept an answer out of the answers given, so that anyone visiting your question (or even before visiting it) can see, that the issue was solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here (mentioned in the other answers) because of different handling of string/bytes types (3 lines of code are affected) and indexing of objects (1 line affected) in Python 2 and 3. The following runs ok after the adjustments (in 4 lines of code) were done:

```
import random
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
    "class %%%(%%%):":
      "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
      "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
      "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
    "*** = %%%()":
      "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
    "***.***(@@@)":
      "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@.",
    "***.*** = '***'":
      "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

# do they want to drill phrases first
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True
else:
    PHRASE_FIRST = False

# load up the words from the website
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())


def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
                   random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(str(WORDS), param_count)))

    for sentence in snippet, phrase:
        result = sentence[:]
        # print(type(result))

        # fake class names
        for word in class_names:
            # print(type(word))
            result = result.replace("%%%", word.decode("utf-8"), 1)

        # fake other names
        for word in other_names:
            result = result.replace("***", word.decode("utf-8"), 1)

        # fake parameter lists
        for word in param_names:
            result = result.replace("@@@", word.decode("utf-8"), 1)

        results.append(result)

    return results


# keep going until they hit CTRL-D
try:
    while True:
        for i, item in enumerate(PHRASES.keys()): 
          print(i, "###", item)

        snippets = list(PHRASES.keys())
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        for snippet in snippets:
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question = list(answer)
                answer = list(question)

            print(question)

            input("> ")
            print("ANSWER:  %s\n\n" % answer)
except EOFError:
    print("\nBye")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this

`snippets = PHRASES.keys()`

with this

`snippets = list(PHRASES.keys())`

As is says in the link you provide, `dict.keys()` does not return a list in python 3.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll need to be aware that there are a few differences between Python 2.X and Python 3.5.x.

The answer from @jprokbelly will get you part of the way there, but you'll also need to modify the code in the `convert` function, because the `urlopen` from `urllib.request` will return byte streams instead of strings, which will cause the error message:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

So if you want to use this code with Python 3.5.x then you'll need to do at least two things.

1. Change the `snippets = PHRASES.keys()` to `snippets = list(PHRASES.keys()]`
2. Change the beginning of the `convert` method to:

   ```
   def convert(snippet, phrase):
       class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
       other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
       class_names = [name.decode('UTF-8') for name in class_names]
       other_names = [name.decode('UTF-8') for name in other_names]
   ```

You're other choice is to setup your dev environment to use virtualenv and run the code in Python 2.7.x.