# Trying to exctract a char from a list

Tags: python

So I have a list of chars like

```
nodeList = ['A','C','E','G']
```

and I want to extract the A. So I found the list[number] method for extracting from a list. But when I put

```
node = nodeList[0]
```

I get an error saying that "'dict_keys' object does not support indexing." So how can I work around this? Thanks.

Comment: Please share a proper snippet and the exact error

Comment: Clearly, `nodeList != ['A','C','E','G']`. Please check what `nodeList` actually is. Spoiler: it's a 'dict_keys' object.

Comment: you are probably doing `nodeList = some.dict.keys()` somewhere in your code. Instead you should do `nodeList = list(some.dict.keys())`. Then you will be able to do `nodeList[0]`

Comment: Sharing code that we can't verify -1

Comment: You should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17322707/2063361)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `nodeList` is not actually a list, but a `dict_keys` object. Before trying to index it, you may simply convert it to a list:

```
nodeList = list(nodeList)
node = nodeList[0]
```

Comment: That worked. thanks

Comment: @IvanJones If it worked, please select this as the correct answer.