# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object while trying to plot data from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

"""
I am trying to plot a graph from data retrieved from a CSV file. The code is as below
"""

```
path = '/Users/pradeepallath/Documents/000_Edureka_Training/001_PredictiveAnalysis/Weather_WWII'
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv(path+'/Weather.csv',low_memory=False,nrows=1000)
dataset.plot(x='MinTemp',y='MaxTemp',style=0)
plt.plot()
```

"""
I am Getting this error. Please note I am new to Python

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/Users/pradeepallath/Documents/Pycharm/Big_Mart_Sale/Mean_Sale.py", line 13, in <module>
            dataset.plot(x='MinTemp',y='MaxTemp',style=0)
          File "/Users/pradeepallath/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 794, in __call__
            return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
          File "/Users/pradeepallath/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py", line 62, in plot
            plot_obj.generate()
          File "/Users/pradeepallath/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 281, in generate
            self._make_plot()
          File "/Users/pradeepallath/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 1063, in _make_plot
            style, kwds = self._apply_style_colors(colors, kwds, i, label)
          File "/Users/pradeepallath/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 723, in _apply_style_colors
            nocolor_style = style is None or re.match("[a-z]+", style) is None
          File "/Users/pradeepallath/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 173, in match
            return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
        TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

    Thanks for the assistance
```

"""

Comment: May be change the columns data type using astype(str), check this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: No it did not work, tried converting using the following command.

dataset.astype({'MinTemp':'int32'},).dtypes
dataset.astype({'MaxTemp':'int32'}).dtypes

Comment: Check what types it is first. dataset.dtypes should give that information.

Comment: Load the CVS into a DataFrame first, then check the dtype property of the columns to isolate the error. Pandas has a bad habit of switching data types behind your back. Avoiding chaining a load and operation in the same cell (if you're in jupyter lab/notebook), or both in the same command within an interpreter will help you out, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's taking issue with `style=0`.
Pandas supports matplotlib line styles.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359951/is-there-a-list-of-line-styles-in-matplotlib) is a good stackoverflow question on how you can see valid options, but essentially the integer zero is not a valid line style.