# cycling through list of linestyles when plotting columns of a matrix in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, linestyle

I am probably missing something obvious. I'm plotting the data contained in the columns of a matrix in a single call using

```
plot(x,A)
```

where is `x` is a 1D numpy arange with a length equal to the number of rows of A.
The lineplots this generates are all full lines with a color cycling through the default color cycle set in matplotlib.rc

I know I can modify the color cycle (and can even have a single color and linestyle for all columns). However how can I only cycle the line styles (say through full, dashed, dash-dotted, dotted) and not the color (I want to keep it black) and still keep the simple SINGLE plot call ?

```
plot(x,A,['k-','k--','k-.','k:'])
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38986038/321973 (combined cycling through color and linestyle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The related source is in `class _process_plot_var_args()` in `axes.py`, as you can see, only the color cycle is defined. A similar linestyle cycle is not possible.

Therefore we need to do these:

```
A=range(10)
B=np.random.randn(10,12)
p_list=plt.plot(A, B)
line_cycle=['-','--','-.',':']
_=[l.set_linestyle(st) for l, st in zip(p_list, np.repeat(line_cycle, 1+(len(p_list)/len(line_cycle))))]
```

[image]

Comment: thx! and also nice of teaching me the use of `_` assignment. That is a nice way to keep the compactness of the generator expression without creating unnecessary variables. I didnt know that one.