# how do I have matplotlib change line markers automatically?

Tags: python, matplotlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can i cycle through line styles in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799156/can-i-cycle-through-line-styles-in-matplotlib)
>    [matplotlib - black & white colormap (with dashes, dots etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358118/matplotlib-black-white-colormap-with-dashes-dots-etc)

I'm using matplotlib (python) and I am plotting several lines on a single plot.

By default, python is assigning a different color to each line, but I want it to assign different line types and just use black for all of them.

I know I could make a list of different line types and use them, but that involves grabbing all the line types and adding them to each script I want to plot multiple lines with. I figure  there has to be an automatic way.

Comment: it is indeed a duplicate of both of those questions. I missed them while searching.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that is possible *that* automatically you would want, but it is certainly doable with a very little effort.  The way I do in my plots, I do all the plotting I want, then I change the markers.  However, in my experience finding a right marker cycle depends on the graph you want to show and on the context the graph appears.  I would verily encourage you to opt for this manual selection of markers and find out what looks the best on your graphs. Following a little sketch showing the way I do (but you've already mentioned something similar in your question):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure(1); f.clf()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5])
ax.plot([5,4,3,2,1])
ax.plot([2,3,2,3,2])

import itertools
for l, ms in zip(ax.lines, itertools.cycle('>^+*')):
    l.set_marker(ms)
    l.set_color('black')

plt.show()
```