# Matplotlib, plot grey plots for academic papers

Tags: python, matplotlib

Many plots are in different colours, how can I plot charts only using black colour and use different markers to distinguish them, here is an example:

[image]

Comment: There is nothing special about black and gray charts. You just use `'black'` (or `'k'`) for black color and `'gray'` for gray color. Rest everything stays the same: markers, line styles, line widths, marker sizes etc. To have different shades of black, refer [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html)

Comment: @Bazingaa Hi, how can I plot a marker with while colour filled in and the border in black?

Comment: You use `markerfacecolor='white'` and `markeredgecolor='black'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Official documentation: [matplotlib.pyplot.plot](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)
- Official example: [pyplot_three](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_three.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-three-py)
- Good summary: [Monochrome (Black & white) plots in matplotlib](http://olsgaard.dk/monochrome-black-white-plots-in-matplotlib.html#Line-and-marker-styles)
- Good package: [cycler](https://matplotlib.org/cycler/)
- Similar or duplicate question: [matplotlib - black & white colormap (with dashes, dots etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358118/matplotlib-black-white-colormap-with-dashes-dots-etc)