# Get colors from matplotlib style

Tags: python, matplotlib

What I would like to achieve:

I want to create several pie charts on one figure. They all share some categories but sometimes have different ones. Obviously I want all of the same categories to have the same colors.

That is why I created a dictionary which links the categories (= labels) to the colors. With that I can specify the colors of the pie chart. But I would like to use the ggplot color (which come with matplotlib.style.style.use('ggplot')). How can I get those colors to feed them into my dictionary?

```
# set colors for labels
color_dict = {}
for i in range(0, len(data_categories)):
    color_dict[data_categories[i]] = ???

# apply colors
ind_label = 0
for pie_wedge in pie[0]:
    leg = ax[ind].get_legend()
    pie_wedge.set_facecolor(color_dict[labels_0[ind_label]])          
    leg.legendHandles[ind_label].set_color_(color_dict[labels_0[ind_label]])
    ind_label += 1
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Short answer*

To access the colors used in the `ggplot` style, you can do as follows

```
In [37]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                  

In [38]: plt.style.use('ggplot')                                                          

In [39]: colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']                       

In [40]: print('\n'.join(color for color in colors))                                      
#E24A33
#348ABD
#988ED5
#777777
#FBC15E
#8EBA42
#FFB5B8
```

In the above example the colors, as RGB strings, are contained in the list `colors`.

Remember to call `plt.style.use(...)` before accessing the color list, otherwise you'll find the standard colors.

---

*More detailed explanation*

The answer above is tailored for modern releases of Matplotlib, where the plot colors and possibly other plot properties, like line widths and dashes (see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38120100/2749397)) are stored in the `rcParams` dictionary with the key `'axes.prop_cycle'` and are contained in a new kind of object, a [`cycler`](https://matplotlib.org/cycler/) (another explanation of a `cycler` is contained in my answer referenced above).

To get the list of colors, we have to get the `cycler` from `rcParams` and then use its `.by_key()` method

> ```
> Signature: c.by_key()
> Docstring: Values by key
>
> This returns the transposed values of the cycler.  Iterating
> over a `Cycler` yields dicts with a single value for each key,
> this method returns a `dict` of `list` which are the values
> for the given key.
>
> The returned value can be used to create an equivalent `Cycler`
> using only `+`.
>
> Returns
> -------
> transpose : dict
>     dict of lists of the values for each key.
> ```

to have a dictionary of values that, at last, we index using the key `'color'`.

---

*Addendum*
<sub>Updated, 2023-01-01.</sub>

It is not strictly necessary to `use('a_style')` to access its colors, the colors are (possibly) defined in a `matplotlib.RcParams` object that is stored in the dictionary `matplotlib.style.library`.
E.g., let's print all the color sequences defined in the different styles

```
In [23]: for style in sorted(plt.style.library):
    ...:     the_rc = plt.style.library[style]
    ...:     if 'axes.prop_cycle' in the_rc:
    ...:         colors = the_rc['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
    ...:         print('%25s: %s'%(style, ', '.join(color for color in colors)))
    ...:     else:
    ...:         print('%25s: this style does not modify colors'%style)
          Solarize_Light2: #268BD2, #2AA198, #859900, #B58900, #CB4B16, #DC322F, #D33682, #6C71C4
      _classic_test_patch: this style does not modify colors
             _mpl-gallery: this style does not modify colors
      _mpl-gallery-nogrid: this style does not modify colors
                      bmh: #348ABD, #A60628, #7A68A6, #467821, #D55E00, #CC79A7, #56B4E9, #009E73, #F0E442, #0072B2
                  classic: b, g, r, c, m, y, k
          dark_background: #8dd3c7, #feffb3, #bfbbd9, #fa8174, #81b1d2, #fdb462, #b3de69, #bc82bd, #ccebc4, #ffed6f
                     fast: this style does not modify colors
          fivethirtyeight: #008fd5, #fc4f30, #e5ae38, #6d904f, #8b8b8b, #810f7c
                   ggplot: #E24A33, #348ABD, #988ED5, #777777, #FBC15E, #8EBA42, #FFB5B8
                grayscale: 0.00, 0.40, 0.60, 0.70
                  seaborn: #4C72B0, #55A868, #C44E52, #8172B2, #CCB974, #64B5CD
           seaborn-bright: #003FFF, #03ED3A, #E8000B, #8A2BE2, #FFC400, #00D7FF
       seaborn-colorblind: #0072B2, #009E73, #D55E00, #CC79A7, #F0E442, #56B4E9
             seaborn-dark: this style does not modify colors
     seaborn-dark-palette: #001C7F, #017517, #8C0900, #7600A1, #B8860B, #006374
         seaborn-darkgrid: this style does not modify colors
             seaborn-deep: #4C72B0, #55A868, #C44E52, #8172B2, #CCB974, #64B5CD
            seaborn-muted: #4878CF, #6ACC65, #D65F5F, #B47CC7, #C4AD66, #77BEDB
         seaborn-notebook: this style does not modify colors
            seaborn-paper: this style does not modify colors
           seaborn-pastel: #92C6FF, #97F0AA, #FF9F9A, #D0BBFF, #FFFEA3, #B0E0E6
           seaborn-poster: this style does not modify colors
             seaborn-talk: this style does not modify colors
            seaborn-ticks: this style does not modify colors
            seaborn-white: this style does not modify colors
        seaborn-whitegrid: this style does not modify colors
     tableau-colorblind10: #006BA4, #FF800E, #ABABAB, #595959, #5F9ED1, #C85200, #898989, #A2C8EC, #FFBC79, #CFCFCF
```

In my understanding

- the `seaborn-xxx` styles that do not modify colors are to be used as the last step in a sequence of styles, e.g., `plt.style.use(['seaborn', 'seaborn-poster'])` or `plt.style.use(['seaborn', 'seaborn-muted', 'seaborn-poster'])`
- also the `_` starting styles are meant to modify other styles, and
- the  only other style,`fast`, that does not modify the colors is all about tweaking the rendering parameters to have a *faster* rendering.

Comment: A great shorthand if you don't need the actual RGB codes: `plt.plot(x, color="C0")` or C1 or C2 etc for the chosen style's colors! Learned this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57028405/5522601

Comment: @smcs Great shorthand, thanks!