# How to access colors from a style used by pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can set the color style for `pyplot` using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('tableau-colorblind10')
```

And list the available color styles using

```
plt.style.available
```

But how can I actually access the colors from the color table? `plt.style` will set a color table for the plots, but I would like to be able to manually select them: select the first and second color used by `plt.plot`.

For example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, sin, cos

plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 200

plt.style.use('tableau-colorblind10')

x = np.linspace(0, pi, 100)
sinx = [sin(xi) for xi in x]
cosx = [cos(xi) for xi in x]
sqrx = [xi*xi for xi in x]

plt.plot(x, sinx, label='sinx')
plt.plot(x, cosx, label='cosx')
plt.plot(x, sqrx, color='k', label='sqrx')
plt.legend()
```

Instead of the black color, I would like to use the blue color from `tableau-colorblind10` again for the `sqrx` plot:

[image]

Comment: Your question [has been asked already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56211675/2749397) and has an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56212312/2749397) that we can summarize as `colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```py
plt.style.library['tableau-colorblind10']

[Out]:
RcParams({'axes.prop_cycle': cycler('color', ['#006BA4', '#FF800E', '#ABABAB', '#595959', '#5F9ED1', '#C85200', '#898989', '#A2C8EC', '#FFBC79', '#CFCFCF']),
          'patch.facecolor': '#006BA4'})
```

Thus, the color should be [#006BA4](https://www.google.com/search?q=%23006BA4&oq=%23006BA4&aqs=chrome..69i57.48514j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and set it to the line you wanna:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi, sin, cos

plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 200

plt.style.use('tableau-colorblind10')

x = np.linspace(0, pi, 100)
sinx = [sin(xi) for xi in x]
cosx = [cos(xi) for xi in x]
sqrx = [xi*xi for xi in x]

plt.plot(x, sinx, label='sinx')
plt.plot(x, cosx, label='cosx')
plt.plot(x, sqrx, color='#006BA4', label='sqrx')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to the cycle colours as c1, c2 etc. For example:

```py
plt.plot(x, sqrx, color='C1', label='sqrx')
```

Comment: Interesting! it seems like it should be `C0` since the blue color is the first item in the list.

Comment: Yeah I forget if “C0” is defined.